# Find critical values calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a $f(x)=-8\sqrt{x}+x$.  I know $f'(x)=-8/(2\sqrt{x})+1$.

I am setting $f'(x)=0$.

I am having trouble clearing the radical in the denominator in order to solve for $f'(x)=0$.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: If $f'(x) = 0$, then rearrange this to be $$\frac{8}{2 \sqrt x} = 1$$ or as $$4 = \sqrt x$$

Comment: could you solve this equation? $$0=-\frac{8}{2t}+1$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us find the critical points of $f(x)$.
$$f(x)=-8\sqrt{x}+x\implies f'(x)=-8\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot x^{-1/2}+1=-\frac{4}{\sqrt{x}}+1$$
Now, we need to find when $f'(x)$ is equal to $0$ or undefined [[1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CriticalPoint.html)]. Clearly, we can see that $f'(x)$ is undefined when $x=0$. We are only searching for values of $x$ that are in the domain of $f(x)$, so we will not consider negative values of $x$. Let us find values of $x$ that will have $f'(x)=0$.
$$f'(x)=0\implies0=-\frac{4}{\sqrt{x}}+1\implies1=\frac{4}{\sqrt{x}}$$
Multiply each side of the equation by $\sqrt{x}$.
$$\sqrt{x}=4\implies x=16$$
Thus, $f(x)$ only has two critical points in its domain; they are $x=0$ and $x=16$.